# Mockito NullPointerException From Super Class Method Call

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit4

I have the following stripped down classes (let's pretend the Service interface just has the single overriden method for simplicity).  No matter what I try, I always get a NullPointerException when the `ServiceImpl` calls `getSqlSession()` .  How can I override this call to avoid the exception?  I have tried creating a spy ServiceImpl and calling `when` on the method `getSqlSession()`, but I still get the exception.  I do not want to put the logic within `ServiceImpl.getData()` that changes the `List<Object>` into a `Map<String,Object>` into the test class since if this implementation ever changes, the test code needs to be changed also.  Any suggestions?

```
public class ServiceImpl extends BaseService implements Service {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceDAO serviceDao;

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getData() {
        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        List<Object> resultSet = service.getData(getSqlSession());
        map.put("Test", resultSet.get(0));
        map.put("Test2", resultSet.get(1));

        return map;
    }

   public void setServiceDao(final ServiceDAO serviceDao) {
     this.serviceDao = serviceDao;
   }

}
```

The BaseService:

```
public class BaseService {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public SqlSession getSqlSession() {
        return (SqlSession)context.getBean("SQL_SESSION");
    }

    public void setContext(ApplicationContext context) {
        this.context=context;
    }

}
```

The DAO

```
public class ServiceDAO {
    public List<Object> getData(SqlSession sqlSession) {
        return sqlSession.selectList("proc_name");
    }
}
```

And the Test Class:

```
public class ServiceImplTest {

    private Service service;

    @Mock
    private ServiceDAO serviceDao;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        service = new ServiceImpl();
        service.serviceDao = this.serviceDao;
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetData() {
        Mockito.when(service.getData()).then(new Answer<List<Object>>() {

        @Override
        public List<Object> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            return serviceDAO.getData(new DefaultSqlSession(null,null));

        }

    });

        service.getData();

    }
}
```

Comment: may be @Spy annotation will help

Comment: Was able to get this working finally using a spy, thanks

Comment: Thanks glad it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was finally able to get this working with below test class.  Had to change the `Service` declaration from the Interface to the actual Impl class.  Not sure if there is any way around this as all other attempts have not worked.

```
public class ServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private ServiceDAO serviceDAO;

    @Spy
    private ServiceImpl service;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        //service = new ServiceImpl();
        service.setServiceDAO(this.serviceDAO);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetData() {
        Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<SqlSession>(){

            @Override
            public SqlSession answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                return new DefaultSqlSession(null,null);
            }

        }).when(service).getSqlSession();

        Mockito.when(service.getData()).then(new Answer<List<Object>>() {

        @Override
        public List<Object> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            return serviceDAO.getData(new DefaultSqlSession(null,null));

        }

    });

        service.getData();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error happens when you try to use the serviceDao from your service:

```
List<Object> resultSet = service.getData(getSqlSession());
```

You need to inject the mocked serviceDAO inside your service, if you are within the same package:

```
@Before
public void before() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    service = new ServiceImpl();
    service.service = this.serviceDAO;
}
```

Comment: I assume you meant `service.serviceDAO = this.serviceDAO;` and I tried that as well.  Did not work.

Comment: No I meant "service.service" within your ServiceImpl the Dao is called "service", and I believe this class is null ? Where do you get the exception exactly ?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct.  Edited the code above to clarify, and also added your changes in (to show I have tried that). but for me I am still getting the exception.  I am getting the exception exactly where you are, every time, right at the call of `service.getData(getSqlSession())`